# Is a 980 TI good for mining?

Tags: mining-profitability

i have a Nvidia 980TI and i just wanted to know if it was worth bitcoin mining. the electricity company I'am with is utillia.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a time that neither CPU nor GPU are good for mining Bitcoin. Nowadays, you got to use ASIC equipments, electronic machines totally specialized in Bitcoin mining.

And from time to time, even the most advanced Bitcoin mining equipments become obsolete.

You should consider mining other cryptocoins, alternative to Bitcoin, also called altcoins. Ethereum, for instance, is still mineable. Other cryptocoins, like Feathercoin, have been conceived to never be mineable by an ASIC.